# Hibernate Tools Generate Classes approach

Tags: code-generation, pojo, hibernate-tools

I would like to know what is the best approach when it comes to update the generated pojo classes should i do it manually or with the hibernate tools, is there any way to tell the Hibernate tools to update only a specific classes and not affect the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind i figure out hibernate utils can actually update a pojos specificly without generating all of them its great